# How to display a html with some data(not current data) without hitting the database

Tags: java, html, database, jsp

I have a web application where I take some input from the user and when the user clicks submit button, the database is queried and the results are displayed in a html page. Now, I have a new requirement where, there is a link on the page(jsp page on which user fills the details) which on clicked has to display the results which were displayed after clicking submit button previously(the most latest results) but should not query the database again. An example should make it clear

Lets say, the user fills the details in the page and click on submit for the first time. The result that is shown is lets say "APPLE". Now the same user comes back and clicks a link(say 'details') on the same page where he filled in details. And meanwhile, the values in the database have changed to say MANGO. Now, when the user clicks on this details link, the result page should show APPLE instead of MANGO(MANGO shud be displayed when the user clicks on submit button and not by clicking 'details' link)

How to achieve this? I dont want to use screen scraping solution. Any better appraoch??

Answer (score 0):

Displaying stale data instead of displaying current data is quite a strange requirement, but if you really want to do this, you could just store the results of the first query in the session, and fetch the details from the session instead of fetching them from the database.

Or you could store the results of the first query in some database table, and get the details from this database table instead of getting them from the "real" database table.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

- **Storing the details on client side**

Use AJAX during first request  and store the details on the client side. And use the details later whenever you require.

- **Storing the details on sever side**

During first request store the details in the user session and fetch from it whenever you require.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily cache the page when user submits the button. and when user clicks on link show the cached version of your page. if he clicks submit again clear the old cache and generate new one. your old link will be pointing your cache file so all will be fine.